# combining multiple queries / query optimization

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have made a little example data that I modify in three steps. I cant do it in one, maybe there is a clever way with some logic? I use Microsoft SQL Server

This code will generate the four base tables with example data and the step by step queries I want to combine, the result at the end should have 8 entries:

Reference table:

```
CREATE TABLE ref 
(
    ID int NOT NULL
    NR int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT KEYS PRIMARY KEY (ID, NR)
);

INSERT INTO ref
VALUES (1234, 223), (1234, 224), (1234, 225),
       (1235, 123), (1235, 124), (1236, 540),
       (1236, 541), (1237, 233), (1237, 234);
```

Con1 table:

```
CREATE TABLE con1 
(
    NR int NOT NULL
    flag int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (NR)
);

INSERT INTO con1
VALUES (123, 0), (124, 1), (125, 0),
       (220, 0), (222, 0), (223, 0), 
       (224, 0), (225, 1), (300, 0),
       (540, 1), (541, 1);
```

Con2 table:

```
CREATE TABLE con2 
(
    NR int NOT NULL
    ID int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (NR)
);

INSERT INTO con2
VALUES (123, 1235), (124, 1235), (125, 1243),
       (220, 1296), (222, 1255), (223, 1234),
       (224, 1234), (225, 1234), (300, 1267),
       (540, 1236);
```

Info table:

```
CREATE TABLE info 
(
    NR int NOT NULL
    SNR int NOT NULL
    SSNR int NOT NULL
    Level int not NULL
    CONSTRAINT KEYS PRIMARY KEY (NR, SNR, SSNR)
);

INSERT INTO info
VALUES (123, 1, 1, 1), (123, 1, 2, 2),
       (123, 1, 3, 2), (123, 2, 1, 1),
       (123, 2, 2, 2), (123, 2, 3, 2),
       (124, 1, 1, 1), (124, 1, 2, 2),
       (124, 1, 3, 2), (125, 1, 1, 1),
       (125, 1, 2, 2), (125, 1, 3, 2),
       (125, 1, 4, 3), (125, 1, 5, 3),
       (220, 1, 1, 1), (220, 1, 2, 2),
       (223, 1, 1, 1), (223, 1, 2, 2),
       (224, 1, 1, 1), (224, 1, 2, 2),
       (224, 1, 3, 2), (225, 1, 1, 1),
       (225, 1, 2, 2), (300, 1, 1, 1),
       (300, 1, 2, 2), (300, 2, 1, 1),
       (300, 2, 2, 2), (540, 1, 1, 1),
       (541, 1, 1, 1);
```

Step #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM con1
INNER JOIN con2 ON con1.NR = con2.NR
WHERE con1.flag = 1
```

Step #2:

```
SELECT ref.* 
FROM ref
INNER JOIN step1 ON ref.ID = step1.ID
```

Step #3:

```
SELECT * 
FROM step2
INNER JOIN info ON step2.NR = info.NR
WHERE info.Level = 1
```

I tried some different ways but always get too much resulting rows

the result should look like this:

| ID | NR | Level | SNR | SSNR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 223 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 224 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 225 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1235 | 123 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1235 | 123 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1235 | 124 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1236 | 540 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1236 | 541 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

It should be all entries from info with Level=1
excluding:

- all NR that do not occur in the intersection of con1 and con2
- all NR that con1 lists with flag = 0

but including:

- all excluded NR that run with the same ID (according to ref) as any NR **not** excluded prior

the result has the same columns as info with on NR matching IDs from ref

Comment: Have you looked at common table expressions to hold the first two intermediate results?

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the result you desire with the given sample data as tabular text. Also add a comprehensive description what the logic behind producing the result would be.

Comment: I didnt know what common table expressions are. It looks kinda similar to a subquery, but better to use in this case, are there relevant differences in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [**Common Table Expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
with step1 As (
    Select * 
    From con1
    Inner Join con2 On con1.NR = con2.NR
    Where con1.flag = 1
), step2 As (
    Select ref.* 
    From ref
    Inner Join step1 On ref.ID = step1.ID
)
Select * 
From step2
Inner Join info On step2.NR = info.NR
Where info.Level = 1
```